# How to compare the columns of one file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have one file  `File_1.txt`:

```
AA:BB:CC 
a@gmail.comb@gmail.com:c@yahoo.co.in -------------------------- Row1 
x@rediff.com,y@gmail.com:y@yahoo.in:z@redhat@com ---------------Row2
a@yahoo.in,c@gmail.com:b@yahoo.co.in,a@rediff.com:c@uix.xo.in---Row3
```

Here `AA`, `BB`, `CC` are three columns and file is `:` delimited.

In Row 1, if `AA` data matches with the `BB` *or* `AA` with `CC` *or* `BB` with `CC` data then print `Row 1 matched`, if not then print `Row 1 no matched`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ gawk -F: 'FNR > 1 {if ($1 == $2 || $1 == $3 || $2 == $3)
                       print FNR, "match";
                     else
                       print FNR, "no match";}' < File_1.txt
```

Comment: You also need to add a counter, to print which rows matches and which does not

Comment: Thank you. I can modify this as per my requirement. Thank you .. :-)

Comment: Here 1st row is column name. If I want to ignore the first row, then What should I do ?

Comment: it is showing output as : 2 no match
3 no match
It is not showing the matched row.

Comment: AA:BB:CC                       a@gmail.com:b@gmail.com:c@yahoo.co.in x@rediff.com,y@gmail.com:y@yahoo.in:z@redhat@com a@yahoo.in,c@gmail.com:b@yahoo.co.in,a@rediff.com:c@uix.xo.in If single record contain's more than one email id then how to compare those record with the other column records ?

Comment: I've answered your question. Please open a new one if you want to ask a different question. And please try for yourself to apply what you have learned from the answers here.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '{if(!($1==$2||$2==$3||$3==$1))printf("%s","not ");print"matched",$0}' file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
AAAA:0:12
BBBBB:2:2
CCCCC:1:1
DDDD:0:0
EEEEE:1:2
> awk -F: '{if(!($1==$2||$2==$3||$3==$1))printf("%s","not ");print"matched",$0}' temp
not matched AAAA:0:12
matched BBBBB:2:2
matched CCCCC:1:1
matched DDDD:0:0
not matched EEEEE:1:2
```

Comment: Ya..It is working. But my next question is :                                                                  col1:col2:col3 
 row1 a   :b   :c
 row2 x,y :y   :z
 row3 a,c :b,a :c                           Here row 2 - col 1 is having record "x,y" now it is printing "not matched" but my question is , "y" is present in row 2 - col1 as well as row 2 -  col2.  now in this case i want to print that record seperately.